# Orthogonally block diagonalize a special matrix

Tags: matrices, reference-request

Consider a square matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ of the form
$$
A = S D
$$
where $S\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is symmetric and $D\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ diagonal with elements $\pm 1$ on the diagonal. (Observe that this implies that $DD=DD^{-1}=I$). I was wondering whether this class of matrices has been studied in the literature, whether they enjoy some special properties. I'm particularly interested in some block diagonalization form under orthogonal transformation.

Any help/comment is welcome. Thanks in advance.